# Changing a File in Snap

Tags: snap, read-only, notepadqq

I would like to change a Configuration in a Snap File (CodeMirror in the Notepadqq snap) so that I can change the syntax coloring for specific themes.

I know you cannot directly modify snap files, as it is read-only.

So if I wanted to do this, how could I manage doing this?

Comment: Crossposted: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50274077/changing-files-in-a-snap-folder

Comment: **Pick one site or the other to post on**.  StackOverflow is probably not the proper location to post this type of issue, but **[crossposting is bad](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu) and you should not do it.**

Answer (score 3):

Actually there is a way around that. While we can't change a file in snap directly (without rebuilding it - that would be too hard), we can exploit mount's bind functionality to achieve the similar effect.

*Caveat*: I wouldn't recommend doing it permanently, but this can be invaluable for temporary debugging.

I will use certbot as an example. Its `main.py` file is located in `/snap/certbot/952/lib/python3.8/site-packages/certbot/main.py`. First we need to copy it somewhere:

```
$ cp /snap/certbot/952/lib/python3.8/site-packages/certbot/main.py /tmp/main.py
```

Then we edit the copied file:

```
$ echo 'print("no help for you!"); exit(1)' > /tmp/main.py
```

And now we mount the edited file over the original one:

```
$ mount -o ro,bind /tmp/main.py /snap/certbot/952/lib/python3.8/site-packages/certbot/main.py
```

Test the results:

```
$ certbot --help
no help for you!
```

And when you are done, you can unmount the file:

```
$ umount /snap/certbot/952/lib/python3.8/site-packages/certbot/main.py
```

Again, I don't think this is very useful as a permanent solution - major updates to the underlying snap package will break something. If all you want to do is to change some configuration then using built-in configuration methods will be probably much easier and more maintainable.

If for some reason you still want to use this as a permanent solution, then you will need to tweak the idea to persist across reboots - store the changed file in some stable directory (not /tmp/), and make sure the mount happens during startup (I believe that it can be done using /etc/fstab entry).

Comment: As others have said, the *real* solution is to go upstream with the desired changes. BUT, if you need the fix from this response to be a little more permanent (eg survive reboots), you can move `main.py` or whichever file you're overwriting to somewhere other than `/tmp` and add this line to `/etc/fstab`: `/path/to/main.py  /snap/some_snap/current/path/to/main.py  auto ro,bind`

Answer (score 2):

Quite simply: you can't do this. Snaps are squashfs images, which are by definition read-only. There's no way around that. Reach out to the maintainers of the snap in question and request this functionality.