# MySQL Workbench and snap - how to change code_editor.xml

Tags: mysql, snap, mysql-workbench

I have MySQL Workbench Community ver 8.0.29 installed as snap.
I would like to change some settings in `code_editor.xml` file.

The full path is `/snap/mysql-workbench-community/10/usr/share/mysql-workbench/data/code_editor.xml` - which is located at read only filesystem `/snap/mysql-workbench-community`.
I suspect the proper way to do that is overriding the file somewhere in `~/snap/mysql-workbench-community` in my home folder.

Has anybody done that before and could support me with the properly working path?

Answer (score 0):

There's a few hacky ways to modify snap installs. Like [unsquashfs](https://snapcraft.io/docs/snap-try) with `snap try` or overwriting a file with [mount](https://askubuntu.com/a/1317611/229500).

But I recommend installing it from apt or dpkg instead.
Download the latest MySQL apt config from
https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/repo/apt/

Then install via

```
sudo dpkg -i mysql-apt-config_w.x.y-z_all.deb
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mysql-workbench-community
```

Make sure the *Tools & Connectors* are enabled when running `dpkg -i`.
*Server & Cluster* and *Preview Packages* can be disabled.
Now you can easily modify the file at `/usr/share/mysql-workbench/data/code_editor.xml`